# Calculating at lower grain and rolling up to higher grains

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am redesigning some legacy code and came across this calculation. Wondering if someone here can point out what the rationale could be for doing something like this? The author is no longer here in the company and there is no documentation either.

The context is: If employee-type is defined as the lowest grain, the weighted average is first calculated at that level and rolled up for higher grain by recalculating the weighted average again.

```
employee department employee_type   salary   weight   location
  A        X           F             1000      3.15    boston
  B        X           P              300      1.27     NY
  C        Y           F             2000      3.38     Tampa
  D        Y           P                       1.12     LA
  E        X           F              3000     3.38     SFO
```

query used for calculating average salary at department:

```
     select department, sum(case when avg_salary is not null then 
      avg_salary*bonus else 0 end)/sum(case when avg_salary is not null then 
     bonus else 1 end)
   from 
     (select employee,department,location,employee_type
    ,sum(weight) as bonus
    ,sum(case when salary is not null then salary*weight else 0 end)/sum(case when salary is not null then weight else 1 end) as avg_salary
    from employee
    group by employee,department,location,employee_type
    )x
    group by  department
```

Output:

```
      X 1752.69230769231
      Y 1502.22222222222
```

If we aggregate at the lowest grain and then compute the average salary at higher grain, we get different values, obviously.

So I guess the question is, which is a correct approach and what the rationale could be behind this approach - is it just to take into account missing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple weighted average.  (Think SumProduct in Excel)

You may notice the NULLIF() in the denominator.  This is to avoid the dreaded divide-by-zero.  I'm sure you know, but you can `Group By` any combination of fields (from the atomic level all the way up).

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([employee] varchar(50),[department] varchar(50),[employee_type] varchar(50),[salary] money,[weight] money,[location] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 ('A','X','F',1000,3.15,'boston')
,('B','X','P',300,1.27,'NY')
,('C','Y','F',2000,3.38,'Tampa')
,('D','Y','P',null,1.12,'LA')
,('E','X','F',3000,3.38,'SFO')

Select Department
      ,WeigtedAvg = sum(Salary*Weight)/NullIf(sum(Weight),0)
 From  @YourTable
 Group By Department
```

**Returns**

```
Department  WeigtedAvg
X           1752.6923
Y           1502.2222
```

**Just for Fun**

```
Select Department
      ,WeigtedAvgBonus = sum(Salary*Weight)/NullIf(sum(Weight),0)
      ,WeigtedAvgRate  = sum(Salary*Weight)/NullIf(sum(Salary),0)
 From  @YourTable
 Group By Department
```

**Returns**

```
Department  WeigtedAvgBonus WeigtedAvgRate
X           1752.6923       3.1793
Y           1502.2222       3.38 -- Notice this matches the only non-null observation in Y
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was thinking the same too - a simple group by department and calculate weighted average. But any idea what the rationale could be for how its implemented currently? Only other thing I can think of is, the source prior to this was in SAS. Perhaps a 1:1 copy of logic?

Comment: @Bee My guess the author did it organically...  One step at a time from the atomic on up.   Seen far worse.